# Returning Data from express server | function call?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to return a response from a backend server, of technologies that match a specific url which is searched on the front end.

My form will submit, and the URL will change, but no results will come through, and no errors appear in the console.

My front end script tag is as follows:

```js
function Submit () {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formResult = new FormData(form);
  const url = '/' + encodeURIComponent(formResult.get('search'));

  const button = document.getElementById('search');
  const sendHttpsRequest = (method, url, data) => {
    return fetch(url, {
      method: method,
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: data ? {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} : {}
    }).then(response => {
      if (response.status >= 400) { //response okay
        return response.json().then(errResData => {
          const error = new Error('Something went wrong');
          error.data = errResData;
          throw error;
        });
      }
      return response.json();
    });
  };

  const getData = () => {
    sendHttpsRequest('GET', '/:url').then(responseData => {
      console.log(responseData);
    });
  };

  button.addEventListener('search', getData);
}
```

Is there something here I am missing? I think it might be a function call, but do I also need to include a function call when I am sending an HTTP request? Where would the function call go in this case? What would it look like?

Comment: Are you sure the server is receiving the GET request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have lots of problems with this.

1. You call `getData` when a button is clicked, but only if that button is clicked after `Search` is called. You never call `Search`.
2. The first thing `Search` does is call `e.preventDefault`, but `e` isn't defined anywhere.
3. You create `formResult` from a variable called `form` which you never define
4. You create `formResult` when `Submit` is called but it looks more like something you want to do when `getData` is called
5. You set the body of the request with `JSON.stringify(data),` but you've never defined `data` … and if you intended to say `formResult` then that would be a `FormData` object which won't convert to JSON.
6. When you send the request you sent it to `'/:url'` which uses Express parameter syntax … but this is the client-side code so you need to put the actual data there.
7. You define a variable `url` in `Submit` but then you never use it (probably you intended to use it in 6 but forgot and hardcoded a string that didn't make sense instead).
8. You are trying to set a body on a GET request

---

You seem to have thrown a lot of code together without testing it as you went along.

I recommend starting from scratch.

Write a function to be called when you click the button. Have it just prevent the default behaviour and log something to the console.

Then fetch the form data you want and log that.

Continue to work from there, testing each stage as you go along so you can detect the mistakes like these.

Comment: Visual learner.... what would some of these components look like then? Not all I understand...

Comment: Also... I am defining data in my backend of the express server... do I still need to define it on the front end?